# Xampp no carga en otros ordenadores de la red

Tags: xampp

Tengo un ordenador con el xampp y mi ip es 192.168.19.10.

Cuando pongo esa dirección y la carpeta es decir : 192.168.19.10/prueba
me la abre. Pero si quiero hacerlo desde otro ordenador de mi red no me la carga. Alguna solución al problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mas que del `Xampp`, me imagino que el problema estará en como tienes configurada la red, ¿puedes acceder a carpetas de otros equipos? La verdad no piloto mucho de redes, pero creo que irán por ahí los tiros.

Comment: Las respuestas no se usan para aclaraciones de la pregunta, revisa [answer]  por favor!

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienen que estar en la misma red los dos ordenadores y en el mismo segmento de red, después prueba que si hagan ping uno con el otro, y así comprobar que los dos equipos se pueden comunicar.

En el `Firewall` también habilita una regla para que esté libre el puerto 80 o el puerto con el que tienes configurado `Apache`.